# Three rows join mysql two success third no

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have three tables People, Items and Locations. People can have only 1 Items. Locations has no relation to any of 2 tables. I want to get I record join all 3. I did 2 so far people + items but 3rd I keep getting MySQL errors. There's no JOIN ON for location. Any help?

```
SELECT * FROM ITEMS i 
RIGHT JOIN PEOPLE p 
ON (p.ITEM_ID =i.ID) where
 p.ID=3 

RIGHT JOIN 

SELECT * FROM LOCATIONS lo where lo.ID=7
```

Comment: If locations is not related to the other tables, why are you trying to join it to them?

Comment: Can you provide sample input data and results?

Comment: Either People or Items need a reference to Locations.ID. Otherwise, this scenario means nothing :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are no `join` keys in common, then you might want to do a `cross join`.  This produces a Cartesian product, that is, every location for each row selected from `People`/`items`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ITEMS i RIGHT JOIN 
     PEOPLE p 
     ON (p.ITEM_ID =i.ID) cross join
     location l
WHERE p.ID=3
```

By the way, MySQL has a very flexible (and non-standard) `join` syntax.  You can actually leave the `on` clause off of a `join` and it will behave the same as a `cross join`.  That is a bad habit, of course.  If you want a cross join, then use `cross join` explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT peo.id, it.id, loc.id
FROM People as peo
INNER JOIN Items as it on it.id = peo.id
INNER JOIN Locations as loc on loc.id = peo.id
WHERE peo.ID=3
```

Edit:
Your question was edited while I was typing this so my example doesn't match like it used to. Use ITEM_ID and ID as needed.

Although not recommended, you can also use

```
SELECT *
FROM People as peo
INNER JOIN Items as it on it.id = peo.id
INNER JOIN Locations as loc on loc.id = peo.id
WHERE peo.ID=3
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want the location with the `ID` of 7 to appear on every row...

```
SELECT * 
    ,(SELECT loc.name FROM Location loc WHERE loc.ID = 7) AS Location
FROM ITEMS i 
RIGHT JOIN PEOPLE p 
ON (p.ITEM_ID =i.ID)
WHERE p.ID=3
```

OR

```
SELECT * 
FROM ITEMS i 
RIGHT JOIN PEOPLE p 
ON (p.ITEM_ID =i.ID)
CROSS JOIN (SELECT * FROM LOCATIONS lo where lo.ID=7) l 
WHERE p.ID=3
```

OR

```
[several other ways to go about it]
```